# ExpertPdf carousel images

Tags: pdf, converters

Trying to generate the pdf from url using expertpdf. Everything renders as expected except the images inside a carousel. I just get the controls for advancing and going back ... the images inside are completely missing. Have tried delaying the load ... tried to run a javascript to find the carousel control and click the play or pause button, but it seems like the script executes way before the whole thing is loaded. Any ideas guys ? ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a css3 function **calc()** used to set the size of the images inside the carousel not being recognized by the library. We just proceeded to remove the calc() from the height attribute of the image and set it as a fixed number ... now images are being rendered as expected. In short, keep an eye out for css3 and html5 support from these converters as their support might be a little bit behind.